# How to play audio file?

Tags: android, skmaps

How do you actually play the audio file from the SKNavigationListener?

```
     @Override
    public void onSignalNewAdviceWithAudioFiles(String[] audioFiles, boolean specialSoundFile) {}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried already? Code snippets of your attempts would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download) for an example:

```
 @Override
    public void onSignalNewAdviceWithAudioFiles(String[] audioFiles, boolean specialSoundFile) {
        // a new navigation advice was received
        SKLogging.writeLog(TAG, " onSignalNewAdviceWithAudioFiles " + Arrays.asList(audioFiles), Log.DEBUG);
        SKToolsAdvicePlayer.getInstance().playAdvice(audioFiles, SKToolsAdvicePlayer.PRIORITY_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

You can use any other audio player you see fit - the SKTools implementation is provided for convenience.

Comment: I downloaded the project from the website but it seems like the package com.ngx.sdktools is missing from the Skmaps.jar. It won't let me import the sktools package and SKToolsAdvicePlayer cannot be resolved.

Comment: In the Android Studio example, both the SDK and the SDK tools projects can be found in the same project. For Eclipse we had to create 2 different projects

Comment: Alright thank you. I was using Eclipse that was the problem. I added the classes jar to the buildpath and now I can import the sktools package.